# Debian 8- atd process consuming 99% cpu

Tags: debian, at

I’m new to server administration. 
Using Debian 8, a process called atd is consuming 99% of cpu. From googling I found out that atd is a job scheduler, but I didn’t set up any. I just have apache 2 and tomcat 8 running with a java web app. Atq call is also not listing any jobs. Where can I check for logs/ how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Consider the possibility that your server may be compromised.

Comment: I think so. When I shutdown apache2 and kill the process, it doesn't respawn. else it respawns.  It is using a config file called mgeflshghx, but Im not able to find it using locate cmd

Answer (score 0):

You may figure out what atd does by checking which files it uses.

```
ps aux | grep atd
daemon     778  0.0  0.2  26044  2120 ?        Ss   22:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
```

→ PID of atd = 778

```
lsof -p 778
```